# “Add up to” ambiguous?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I was asked for a quote and this is what I said: 
“An infographic costs $10 but since I’ll also be conducting the research, it’s going to add up to $20 per infographic.”
Does the phrase “add up to” add ambiguity to the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound ambiguous to me, maybe just a little informal, and in a conversation, any doubts can be settled easily. More formally, you could say "the price will total $20 per infographic."

Actually, I'm editing my answer to say that it is *very* ambiguous. I didn't see the other possible interpretation until a moment ago. You may be saying that you will be adding as much as an additional $20 to the price, for a total of $30 each. If that is what you mean, you should probably say "add as much as $20 more per infographic, for a total of $30 each."

Comment: In my (UK) experience, we use 'that adds up to', after the mention of amounts, to indicate the final total.

Comment: I agree the phrase *that adds up to* would usually mean a total. But what if you read it as " the research will add as much as (up to) $20 each."

Answer (score 1):

I find the use of "add up to" ambiguous - it either refers to the sum total, or the upper limit of an uncertain amount. The ambiguity lies in the fact that "add up to" can be a phrasal verb indicating the process of summing, but doesn't necessarily indicate adding an amount "up to" some upper limit value.  The sentenced can be parsed as either:

1. An infographic costs $10 but since I’ll also be conducting the research, it’s going to be a sum total of $20 per infographic. [The price per graphic is a flat $20.]
2. An infographic costs $10 but since I’ll also be conducting the research, it’s going to add an additional charge of up to $20 per infographic. [The price may be between $10 and $30 depending on the amount of research needed.]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Maybe it's better to avoid using "add up to" altogether and write more to the point, like this:

> An infographic costs $10 but since I'll also be conducting the research, **the cost (including research) will be between $10 to $30** per infographic.

or, if you mean that the research cost itself is between $0 to $10,

> An infographic costs $10 but since I'll also be conducting the research, **the cost (including research) will be between $10 to $20** per infographic.

Comment: In the first interpretation, the price "<adds up> to $20 per infographic" - the price is a flat $20, not a maximum. Only in the second interpretation where the price "<adds up to> $20 per infographic" is the price uncertain with a maximum of $30.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Really?  I thought my original 1st example was clear enough.  Anyway, I rewrite my answer.

Comment: I still interpret "it's going to add up to $20 per infographic" a little different. Either it means 1) it's going to sum ("add up") to $20 per infographic total, or 2) it's going to add an additional charge on top of the $10 which may be as large as ("up to") $20.